# What is the name of the executable file from /proc/[PID]/cmdline?

Tags: c, pid, proc

As per the man page for /proc/[PID]/cmdline: This read-only file holds the complete command line for the the process where The command-line arguments as a set of strings separated by null bytes ('\0'), with a further null byte after the last string.

I'm writing a C program that will take a specific PID and I will want to get the name of the executable by opening the cmdline file. However, I'm not exactly sure what the contents mean, specifically where will the name for the executable file be exactly located?

For instance, running a /proc/4404/cmdline provides the following output:

```
/usr/bin/whoopsie-f
```

A couple more examples:

```
/sbin/init/splash
/lib/systemd/systemd--user
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon--system--address=systemd:--nopidfile--systemd-activation--syslog-only
```

How do I exactly decipher this output? Is the name of executable exactly in a fixed location (if so can you please point out where?). I've also seen other threads that run the command: "readfile exe", but I'm trying to do this all in C and specifically need to utilize the cmdline file to access the name of executable.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you pipe the output to e.g. `xxd` to see a hex-dump of it. There's a separator there that's not really visible otherwise. It's easy to use in C though.

Comment: Each of the "argvs" in the file are `nul` terminated strings. With C you can just repeatedly do `strcpy`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah but how will I know which one is the name of executable?

Comment: @aDabOfRanch the first one. Just like C - `argv[0]`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya so If cmdline contains the input /usr/bin/whoopsie-f then per argv[0] the name of the executable is usr?

Comment: @aDabOfRanch no, the `nul` in that case would be after `...whoopsie`. So the executable will be `/usr/bin/whoopsie`. Have you check the hex-dump like SomeProgrammerDude suggested?

Comment: @aDabOfRanch try - `cat /proc/4404/cmdline | xxd` and look on the left side. There will be a `00` after the `e` from `whoopsie`. If the textual representation it will appear as a `.`, but remember it is not a period. A period as ASCII value of `0x2e`. This is `0x00`. `xxd` is just showing it as a dot because it is a not printable character.

Comment: If you want to get the name of the executable, then better look at /proc/pid/exe

Comment: suggest using `basename()` on the contents of each line.  This will result in a pointer to the basename I.E. the executable name

Comment: the first entry in the 'cmdline' is the 'path/execname'